# How to move www directory to home?

Tags: ubuntu-one, home-directory, cloud, dropbox, www

I've recently installed Lamp in my fresh 12.04 installation. I want to know if I can move my www directory to home so I can syncronize it with Ubuntu One, or is there any way to syncronize www directory with dropbox or some other application. I just want to keep that directory syncronized with the cloud storage so I never lose the data.

Thanks in advance. :-)

Comment: You can as you can see in the answers but I would keep everything as is, create a cronjob to make a gzipped file and store that file elsewhere (usb stick/drive but it could also be your Ubuntu one synch dir).

Comment: If that's the case, I would suggest you to use some kind of backup system in order to backup your /var/www folder in a cloud folder. This way you can also keep also snapshots of the changes that you make to your website. Dejá Dup and Back in the time comes to my mind.

Answer (score 1):

The solution provided in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/76961/9598) is yet effective for your needs even in Ubuntu 12.04.

Placed here for your convenience.

> You can change your default folder for www content by editing the
>   information provided inside the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`
>   file. By dropping `sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/default`
>   and changing any occurrence of the `/var/www` or (maybe your case)
>   `/var/www/html` and setting the folder that you wish to use.
>
> The contents of the file will look like this:
>
> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
>
>   DocumentRoot /home/geppettvs/www
>   <Directory />
>       Options FollowSymLinks
>       AllowOverride None
>   </Directory>
>   <Directory /home/geppettvs/www/>
>       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
>       AllowOverride None
>       Order allow,deny
>       allow from all
>   </Directory>
>
>   ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
>   <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
>       AllowOverride None
>       Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
>       Order allow,deny
>       Allow from all
>   </Directory>
>
>   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
>
>   # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
>   # alert, emerg.
>   LogLevel warn
>
>   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
>
>     Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
>     <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
>         Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
>         AllowOverride None
>         Order deny,allow
>         Deny from all
>         Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
>     </Directory>
>
> </VirtualHost>
> ```
>
> In this case I am using my `/home/geppettvs/www` folder in order to
>   place the files that will be exposed to the public via http
>   connections (port 80).

Give this a try. I hope this help you.

However, I suggest you to run a search before opening a new question. Your question may be closed as du

Good luck!

Comment: I did run a search but couldn't find an answer.
Well, thank you so much. It worked but I preferred to keep the directory secure and set the default backup app of Ubuntu to automatically backup the data of www directory to Ubuntu one.

Comment: Good to know it worked, and also good to know you have chosen one of the best choices for you. Anyway I suggest you to have a look at the answers of this question http://askubuntu.com/q/219615/9598 in order to see the differences. Good luck!