# File permission problem on Ubuntu Lamp server

Tags: 14.04, permissions, apache2, lamp

Please don't mark it as duplicated. I've tried a lot but can't make it working.

I've installed LAMP using tasksel.
Everything is fine but having file permission error (While installing WordPress I get this error "Sorry, but I can’t write the wp-config.php file." )

I can create the file manually but I don't want to do this. I wasn't to make it working correctly.

What I did to set up permission after installing lamp

`cd /var/wwww/
sudo chown -R username:www-data /var/www/html/
sudo chmod 775 /var/www/html/
sudo chmod g+s /var/www/html/`

Later I tried some solutions like `sudo chown -R [USER NAME]:[USER NAME] /var/www` which I found on askubuntu.

I don't know much about permission issue trying solution blindly.

Can you please help me on this to make it working? :)

Output of `ls -l /var/www`
`Output of total 4
drwxrwsr-x 3 h3mdsa h3mdsa 4096 Jun 12 16:40 html`
(Thanks @Jos for comment)

Thanks in advanced,
Md Al Amin

Comment: At this point, what is the output of `ls -l /var/www`? Please add this to your question.

Comment: Try: `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www`. That should work. You were close.

Comment: Hey it works like a magic.  Can you please tell me why `sudo chown -R username:www-data /var/www/html/` didn't work? I used it on other machine 2 month ago. It worked but didn't work this time. Anyway thanks for help.

Comment: Hard to tell why that did work on the other machine - it shouldn't have worked. Apache2 runs with user name `www-data` and executes PHP statements as that user. Allow me to rewrite my comment as an answer.

Comment: If Jos his answer is correct why is this NOT a duplicate? Hmm? @alamin72103 for instance: your method works but does need a change to groups: http://askubuntu.com/questions/353847/apache-permissions or http://askubuntu.com/questions/378351/permissions-and-ownership-of-var-www and many more ;)

Comment: Hi @Rinzwind Thanks for your comment. I told on my question that I don't know much about permission issue. The first link you gave was not helpful for me because he told "I have added the www-data user to my user's group" I didn't know anything like that so I was like an alien word to me and I tried second liked accepted answer which I mentioned on my question. But your comment helped me. I was unable to create folder and file with mouse right click. After adding www-data user to my user's group everything is fine.Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You were close: the directory /var/www/ should be owned by www-data (as a user) and www-data as a group. So the proper command, if things get messed up, is:

`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the group of the web files to your Linux user name or at least add user 'root' to the group "www-data"

```
usermod -a -G www-data root
```

There is also a three-step technique by which you can solve this:

Those three are in the link below.
This post can solve the full problem.

https://www.spookycodes.com/2019/11/09/fix-linux-lamp-server-permission-issues-ultimate-fix-2020/